# Use operator in a query to get difference between two dates with mySQL

Tags: mysql

Assume today is 2nd November...

I have this table:

```
|--------|----------|------------|
| SUB_Id | SUB_Name | SUB_End    |
|--------|----------|------------|
| 1      | Banana   | 2017-11-02 | <- return this row (diff 0 day)
| 2      | Apple    | 2017-11-03 | <- return this row (diff 1 day)
| 3      | Pear     | 2017-11-09 | < don't return this row as diff is > 3
|--------|----------|------------|
```

I'm using this query to get rows when `SUB_End` - today date are <= 3.

```
SELECT * FROM Subscriptions WHERE SUB_End >= curdate() AND SUB_TrialEnd <= curdate() + interval 15 day
```

How I can get the difference calculated from this query ?

For example, for the row

Answer (score 1):

Try DateDiff function in mySQL. Refer [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datediff.aspx)

Comment: Like this ? `SELECT * FROM Subscriptions WHERE DATEDIFF(SUB_End, :today) <= 3`. But how can I get the difference please for matched rows?

Comment: Like this...SELECT s.*, DATEDIFF(SUB_End, :today) FROM Subscriptions s WHERE DATEDIFF(SUB_End, :today) <= 3

Comment: So the query calculates two times the difference ?

Comment: Will use `HAVING nb_days <= 16`.